# RadTreeView NodeEditing change behaviour

Tags: telerik, radtreeview

By default RadTreeNode becomes editable after (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_radtreeview_allownodeediting.html)

"End-users can edit the text of tree-nodes by pressing F2 when the node is selected or by clicking on a node that is already selected (slow double click)."

This is unconvenient, that whatever was clicked twice start being edited, even if clicks are spearated by far.

How I can change its behaviour so edit happens on normal, fast double-click?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you just have to rely on context menu approach, and start editing item from context menu handler.     AllowNodeEditing="False" can be set, yet  OnNodeEdit="HandleNodeEdit" and the like will still work, when editing is triggered manually using appropritate client API function from context menu handler function.